# Where is the location of the config/packages/twig.yaml

Tags: php, symfony, twig

we defined some namespaces in the `twig.yaml`, but they are not working.
where have to be the `twig.yaml` for working?
we get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Twig\Error\LoaderError: There are no registered
> paths for namespace

the twig installation is in the following folder
`/vendor/twig/twig/src/....`

thank you for your help!

Comment: Title seems a bit strange.  Are you using the Symfony framework or is this a standalone sort of thing?

Comment: Please post your Twig.yaml code, so we can help find the problem.

Answer (score -1):

check the manual out

https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#global-variables

you have to define the twig variables like this

```
// config/packages/twig.yaml
twig:
  default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'
  globals:
    one:
      part_1: '%one.part_1%'
    two:
      part_1: '%two.part_1%'
      part_2: '%two.part_2%'
      part_3: '%two.part_3%'
```

the twig values in your twig config file can have several destinations like this

```
// config/services.yaml
parameters:
  one.part_1: '1.0.0'
  two.part_1: 'xyz'
  two.part_2: 'ghj'
  two.part_3: '485'
```

you can also define env values out of your env file but be careful with this, you can access them overall in twig templates

you can access this variables in your twig templates like this

```
{{ one.part_1 }}
{{ two.part_1 }}
{{ two.part_2 }}
{{ two.part_3 }}
```

Comment: The question is about twig namespaces not global twig variables.  And I suspect that they are not using the Symfony framework at all so all this config stuff is irrelevant.